# If I suspend and resume my vmware host vista box, I have to restart the VMware NAT service or my guest Linux DNS requests won't resolve

Tags: nat, vmware-workstation

If I suspend and resume my VMware host (Workstation 6.5) Vista box, I have to manually restart the VMware NAT service or my guest Linux (Ubuntu) DNS requests won't resolve.

I can ping boxes on the network by ip address, but just not resolve DNS.

(My problem is related to the issue described here:
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/185756)

Any suggestions for why this is an issue?  It is an annoyance!

Answer (score 0):

Switch the VM to operate the network in a bridged mode instead.